# tcpdf and image with bad links

Tags: php, tcpdf

i use latest TCPDF version. If the text is a picture of a bad link shows an error and do not generate a PDF file.

Is it possible to disable this error? 
If you did not find the image to generate the PDF, but without a picture.

I hope to understand my problem,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not advisable to comment the error about images on tcpdf because all the errors are hardcoded.

In the tcpdf_config.php, you will see the path of the image that tcpdf look when you tried to display images. Make sure all the images you want to display in the pdf is in that folder.

```
define ('K_PATH_IMAGES', '/images/');
```